# Hide gridview column header

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated from a sqldatasource with ajax, which is fired from a radcombox drop down. The below does not work because technically the gridview hasn't loaded. Is there an easy work around?

```
Protected Sub RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles RadComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You da man John, keep up the good work.

Answer (score 21):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False">
        </asp:GridView>
```

**showheader=false** on the aspx page

Answer (score 4):

Just hide the cell after the entire GridView is bound in the DataBound event:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Visible = False
End Sub

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
```

Just know that this only hides the contents of the header cell, not the entire column.

Comment: Getting a Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on page load for the Visible=False line.

Comment: Ok, do you have a HeaderRow? Can you please update your question with your GridView markup?

Comment: I said screw it and just went this route with the hidden css class https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/grid-view-header-text-112199.aspx. Worked

Comment: Ok, it looks like those all suggest the same thing. They just use CSS to hide it instead of the `Visible` property. As long as it works I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Write code line after Data Bind method or after binding grid on Page Load method

```
   GridView1.DataBind();
   if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)// check if grid not empty
      {
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;//hide grid column header
            GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;//hide grid column value
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Visible = false;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the entire column.

`GridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False`